# Changing input field color if filled

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form with `input` elements:

```
<form method="POST" action="User.do">
    <div id="buddy-form-group">

          <input type="text"
             class="form-control form-input-field form-interests-input-field" 
             name="interests" 
             onchange="checkFilled()">

     </div>

     <br/><br/><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I have a scrip that takes all elements of class `form-interests-input-field` and checks if they are empty. If empty, it sets the color to red, else to green:

```
function checkFilled()  {
    var interests = document.getElementsByClassName("form-interests-input-field");
    for (var i = 0; i<interests.length; i++)  {
        if (interests[i].value = "")  {
            interests[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        else  {
            interests[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }   

    }
}
```

The problem is, the color of **all** fields gets changed to green if at least one field gets field. Once they are green, it never changes to red, even if I erase all the input. I suspect the script puts the green color property on class, rather than individual element. What is the best way to fix it?

Comment: You should be using `==` instead of `=` in your first `if` statement

Comment: @Aaron Garton Thank you! Now I feel silly. You can post it as an answer or I can delete a question.

Comment: haha a common mistake ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
<script>
    function checkFilled()  {
        var interests = document.getElementsByClassName("form-interests-input-field");
        for (var i = 0; i<interests.length; i++)  {
            if (interests[i].value == '')  {
                interests[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            } else {
                interests[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            }   
        }
    }
</script>

<form>
    <div id="buddy-form-group">

          <input type="text"
             class="form-control form-input-field form-interests-input-field" 
             name="interests" 
             onkeyup="checkFilled()">

     </div>

     <br/><br/>
     <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkFilled()" type="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Changed the `=` to `==` in the `if` statement.

With the addition of the `onkeyup` and `onclick` fields, it does what you want. When you click the button, it checks the value of the input field and sets the background color accordingly. It also sets the input field's background color as you type.

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to do this by using css. This worked for me.

```
 input:not([value = ""]){
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
```